# Best Package To Use For General Coordinate Plane Diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I am trying to create diagrams similar to the following, without being too verbose,

[image: Image Example]

What would be the best way to create this?

Comment: TikZ would be one of the ways.  There are ridiculously many examples of such diagrams on this site.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far!

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic as they usually do not revolve around an abstract issue.  Instead, [describe the problem](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @HenriMenke Do you have a reference for that definition of 'off-topic'? How do you define 'abstract'? It seems to me that many on-topic questions concern very concrete issues, so 'non-abstract' is not off-topic in that sense. If anything, 'which package to use for diagrams of type X?' is rather more abstract than questions concerning particular problems and attempted solutions, which are anything but. If you object to the lack of code, say so. Why invoke a highly questionable notion of 'on-topic' if the issue is no code? (Code being anything but abstract, of course.)

Comment: @cfr https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @HenriMenke I see nothing there about not asking 'abstact' questions or any explanation of what 'abstract' means in the sense you're using it. I even search the page for 'abstract' because I was sure I must have missed it. Nothing there even suggests that abstract questions are off-topic. Some of the question types described there are not 'off-topic', but shouldn't be asked for other reasons. But I don't see anything which suggests abstract questions shouldn't be asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An emergency-purpose-only solution with PSTricks. Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` or `xelatex`.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(4.5,3.5)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(4,3)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\pnodes{A}(1,1)(3,2)
\psset{linestyle=dashed,dash=4pt 1pt,arrows=o-o}
\psline(0,0|A0)(A0)(A0|0,0)
\psline(0,0|A1)(A1)(A1|0,0)
\psset{fillstyle=solid,linestyle=solid}
\pscircle(A0){1.8pt}
\pscircle(A1){1.8pt}
\uput[0](A0){$(x,y)$}
\uput[0](A1){$(x',y')$}
\uput[180](0,0|A0){$y$}
\uput[180](0,0|A1){$yS_y$}
\uput[270](A0|0,0){$x$}
\uput[270](A1|0,0){$xS_x$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: use `\psCoordinates(A0)`

Comment: It can use any dot one likes to have ...

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity thanks for the comment, wouldn’t have thought of that

Comment: It is also possible to compile with `pdflatex`, with package `auto-pst-pdf` (to be loaded *after* `pstricks`) if you add to the command pdflatex the option `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) or `--shell-escape` (TeXLive, MacTeX).

Answer (score 2):

It can be a job for the [`mfpic`](https://ctan.org/pkg/mfpic) package, a handy interface to the MetaPost program. (Or for MetaPost itself, but it would be a bit more verbose.)

To be typeset with LaTeX, then MetaPost, and then LaTeX again.

```
\documentclass[12pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[metapost]{mfpic}
    \setlength{\mfpicunit}{1cm}
    \opengraphsfile{\jobname}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfpic}[2]{-.5}{3}{-.5}{2.5}
    \pointdef{M}(.5, 1)
    \pointdef{N}(2, 1.75)
    \dashed\lines{(\Mx, 0), \M, (0, \My)}
    \dashed\lines{(\Nx, 0), \N, (0, \Ny)}
    \doaxes{xy}
    \pointfillfalse
    \point[4bp]{(\Mx, 0), \M, (0, \My), (\Nx, 0), \N, (0, \Ny)}
    \tlpointsep{3bp}
    \tlabels{[tr](0, 0){$O$} [tc](\Mx, 0){$x$} [tc](\Nx, 0){$S_xx$} [tc](\xmax, 0){$X$}}
    \tlabels{[cl](\Mx, \My){$(x, y)$} [cl](\Nx, \Ny){$(x', y')$}}
    \tlabels{[cr](0, \My){$y$} [cr]{(0, \Ny)}{$S_yy$} [cr]{(0, \ymax)}{$Y$}}
\end{mfpic}
\closegraphsfile
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with Ti*k*Z, where one can be very *minimalistic* and clean as well

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=4mm, tikz]{standalone}

\tikzset{%
    circ/.style = {%
        draw, solid,
        fill = white,
        shape = circle,
        inner sep = 1pt,
        node contents =
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axes
\draw [->, thick] (0,-1) -- (0,3) node [right] {$y$};
\draw [->, thick] (-1,0) -- (4,0) node [below] {$x$};

%Coordinate lines and nodes
\draw [dashed] (0,1) node [circ, label = left:{$y$}] {}
            -- (1,1) node [circ, label = right:{$(x,y)$}] {}
            -- (1,0) node [circ, label = below:{$x$}] {};
\draw [dashed] (0,2) node [circ, label = left:{$S_y y$}] {}
            -- (3,2) node [circ, label = right:{$(x',y')$}] {}
            -- (3,0) node [circ, label = below:{$S_x x$}] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```